# Joomla's JInput strips HTML with every filter

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to save HTML text to database safely in Joomla 2.5, so I'm using JInput to get the form data.

According to [developer.joomla.org](http://developer.joomla.org/manual/chap-Joomla_Platform_Manual-Input.html), there is HTML filter:

> HTML - Returns a string with HTML entities and tags intact, subject to
>   the white or black lists in the filter.

According to [docs.joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput), there are these filter which should (logically. They are not explained there) pass HTML tags:

> RAW, HTML, SAFE_HTML

At the code [JFilterInput::clean](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php#L194) which JInput uses for filtering, there is no SAFE_HTML filter. I don't know what it is doing in one documentation and why RAW filter is missing in another. Apart from that, all these filters strip HTML tags anyway.

With just $_POST:

```
$_POST['shortDescription'];
```

returns

```
<b>Hello <i>world</i></b>
```

When I use JInput:

```
$input->get('shortDescription', '', 'RAW');
$input->get('shortDescription', '', 'HTML');
$input->get('shortDescription', '', 'SAFE_HTML');
```

all returns just

```
Hello world
```

without HTML tags. What is it for then? How to use it when I need to store HTML safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bypased it with this method:

```
public function getHtmlInput($htmlText)
{
    $input_options = JFilterInput::getInstance(
        array(
            'img','p','a','u','i','b','strong','span','div','ul','li','ol','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5',
            'table','tr','td','th','tbody','theader','tfooter','br'
        ),
        array(
            'src','width','height','alt','style','href','rel','target','align','valign','border','cellpading',
            'cellspacing','title','id','class'
        )
    );

    $postData = new JInput($_POST, array('filter' => $input_options));

    return $postData->get($htmlText, '', 'HTML');
}
```

Usage:

```
$this->getHtmlInput('documentation');
```

I hope this is solved in Joomla 3...

Comment: I just checked this in Joomla! 3.2.2 and it seems that "$my_var = $jinput->get('my_field', 'my default', 'html');" will still incorrectly strip the HTML.
I'll have a dig through the Joomla code though

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$html = JComponentHelper::filterText($jinput->post->get('shortDescription', '', 'raw'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I figured I would throw my 2 cents in as it might help people finding this post searching for a solution.

Using an html editor it still strips the html with using the HTML filter. To get around it I use ARRAY as the filter instead and then just implode the result.

Easy bo breazy.

Comment: This is essentially circumventing the Joomla in-built protections with this method. Be very careful that you trust whoever is using your HTML editor. Otherwise, you are opening yourself up to hosting all kinds of malicious content.

Comment: @JohnRix is correct, I would be pretty sketchy on letting someone submit html from a front-end facing form regardless.  My solution assumes this is an admin side thing where you know it's not going to be malicious.

Answer (score 0):

(In the context of Joomla 3.x) The default configuration of a `JInputFilter` instance is to operate in whitelisting mode, with empty arrays of whitelisted tags and attributes ie. the most restrictive possible mode of HTML filtering that effectively gets rid of everything.

This clearly isn't that useful out of the box, but it is opting for security over convenience, and leaving it up to developers to make a conscious decision to relax the security to accept tags and attributes in the received content by using an alternate JInputFilter instance, either:

A) with a specified whitelist of tags (what @Jon ultimately did in his own answer)

```
$filter = JInputFilter::getInstance(array('img', ...), array('src', ...));
```

or

B) configured to operate in blacklist mode

```
$filter = JInputFilter::getInstance([], [], 1, 1);
```

As an aside, unless you disable the $xssAuto option (see usage below), Joomla will enforce the following blacklists irrespective of which mode the JInputFilter instance is configured with:

**Tags**: 'applet', 'body', 'bgsound', 'base', 'basefont', 'embed', 'frame', 'frameset', 'head', 'html', 'id', 'iframe', 'ilayer', 'layer', 'link', 'meta', 'name', 'object', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'xml'

**Attributes**: 'action', 'background', 'codebase', 'dynsrc', 'lowsrc'

For reference, here is the usage information for the `JFilterInput::getInstance` method:

```
/**
 * Returns an input filter object, only creating it if it doesn't already exist.
 *
 * @param   array    $tagsArray   List of user-defined tags
 * @param   array    $attrArray   List of user-defined attributes
 * @param   integer  $tagsMethod  WhiteList method = 0, BlackList method = 1
 * @param   integer  $attrMethod  WhiteList method = 0, BlackList method = 1
 * @param   integer  $xssAuto     Only auto clean essentials = 0, Allow clean blacklisted tags/attr = 1
 * @param   integer  $stripUSC    Strip 4-byte unicode characters = 1, no strip = 0, ask the database driver = -1
 *
 * @return  JFilterInput  The JFilterInput object.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public static function &getInstance($tagsArray = array(), $attrArray = array(), $tagsMethod = 0, $attrMethod = 0, $xssAuto = 1, $stripUSC = -1)
```

Joomla also provides configurable filtering rules on the Text Filters tab of the Global Configuration page in the administration interface. Here, you can configure the mode of operation, as well as the tags and attributes to be filtered on a per user group basis. To take advantage of this in your own code, use the `JComponentHelper::filterText()` method, per @xavip's answer.